# How to publish mobile services using the file-system option?

Tags: c#, publish, azure-mobile-services

I'd like to publish my [mobile services server project](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/) by using the file-system option.

Azure mobile services does not have to be run in azure, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/10/creating-an-azure-mobile-services-net-backend-from-scratch.aspx) is a good article describing how.

I want to do this because I have customers that do accept azure but others who wants the service in their own environment because they allow no firewall openings and keeps their system closed.

Where is the File-system option? How do I enable it? Is there an agile nice workaround?

[image: Publish]

Answer (score 1):

While you can run the backend outside of Azure, it is meant only for debugging scenarios. A lot of features, like authentication and push, do require the mobile service to be published to Azure.

For connecting to on premise resources, you would need to see if hybrid connections is acceptable to them: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-hybrid-connections-get-started/